# Trigger - cant withdraw more than current balance - the function in use incorrect?

Tags: sql, oracle

So as the title says im trying to assemble a trigger making sure you cannot withdraw more than in the current balance.

```
 Translation;
 Saldo = balance
 Belopp = amount


Create or replace trigger bifer_uttag
 before insert
 on UTTAG
 for each row
 begin
   IF get_saldo  (:new.belopp > :old.belopp)
   Then 
     raise_applicaton_error( -20001, 'snålt saldo!');
   end if;
 end;
```

But I get:

So I suppose it has something with my function(Get_saldo) im calling?

```
create or replace function get_saldo(
p_knr in kontotest.knr%type
)
return number                    
as
v_saldo number := 0 ;
begin
  select sum( saldo) 
   into v_saldo
   from konto                    
   where knr = p_knr ;
  return v_saldo ;
end;
/
```

Appreciate any help.

**Update, getting Errors: TRIGGER BIFER_UTTAG Line/Col: 2/2 PL/SQL: Statement ignored Line/Col: 2/5 PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_SALDO'**

Comment: What is the parameter that your function, get_saldo, is expecting? What are you sending?

Comment: knr = Bankaccount nr

Comment: You are passing `:new.belopp > :old.belopp` to your function. This would be a logical value, not a Bankaccount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER bifer_uttag 
  BEFORE INSERT ON uttag 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF get_saldo(:new.knr) > :new.belopp THEN 
      Raise_application_error(-20001, 'snålt saldo!'); 
    END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: Getting Errors: TRIGGER BIFER_UTTAG Line/Col: 4/1 PL/SQL: Statement ignored Line/Col: 4/1 PLS-00201: identifier 'RAISE_APPLICATON_ERROR' must be declared ... Weird?

Comment: It was it ! Appreciate the help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass account number to your function call and then do comparison -

```
Create or replace trigger bifer_uttag
 before insert
 on UTTAG
 for each row
 begin
 IF get_saldo(:new.knr) > :new.belopp
 Then 
 raise_applicaton_error( -20001, snålt saldo!');
 end if;
 end;
```

Comment: Errors: TRIGGER BIFER_UTTAG Line/Col: 4/2 PL/SQL: Statement ignored Line/Col: 4/15 PLS-00201: identifier 'P_KNR' must be declared

Comment: @TomScott, what is the column in UTTAG that has the account number in it? Use that column in place of p_knr.

Comment: Its knr, and I tested with only (knr) > :new.belopp aswell but no success. Also with p_knr

Comment: Then It should be `:new.knr` or `:old.knr`